# How to pass variables to a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I want to pass parameters to deleteUndone, so that when the user activates completeTodo it calls deleteUndone with specified parameters, but can't figure out how?

```
deleteUndone = e => { 
   do something
}

completeTodo = e => {
   completeUndone(e.target.id)
   do more stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going about it is to create a new function in the render method and pass along the event with any other argument you need.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  deleteUndone = (e, param) => {
    // do something...
  };

  completeTodo = e => {
    completeUndone(e.target.id);
    // do more stuff...
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* ... */}
        <button onClick={e => this.deleteUndone(e, "foo")}> Click me </button>
        {/* ... */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteUndone=(parameter1,parameter2)=>{
    //do some stuff           
}
```

To call deleteUndone use this operator.Assuming that a,b are defined in the state of the component.The arguments may also be defined in within the function scope.

```
completeTodo = e => {    
   const {a,b}=this.state;
   completeUndone(e.target.id)
this.deleteUndone(a,b);
```

}